# How do I use caching in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I'm having some problems with caching with chunks depending on external data files. My Rnw has external code chunks, getResults and printResults, which are read at the start of the Rnw from externalCode.r, and a regular chunk, fileData, which is meant to create the caching dependency.

```
<<setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
read_chunk('externalCode.r')
@  

<<fileData,echo=FALSE,include=FALSE,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, cache.extra=md5sum(c('externalData1.csv','externalData2.csv'))>>=
@

<<getResults, echo=FALSE, dependson='fileData', include=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
@

<<printResults, dev='tikz', dependson='getResults', echo=FALSE, include=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
@
```

This all works if I turn off the caching. However, with caching on changes to the external files do not trigger an update to the cache files fileData*, hence the plot is not updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, there was a change directory in the r code which meant md5sum was returning the same (NA) value despite changes to file, whoops!